# How to resolve error of "Reference counted object is used after it is released"?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am getting following error but how to resolve it ?
Error is highlighted with green circle **"Reference counted object is used after it is released"**
**Edited:** I am using following method

```
+ (NSString *)GetUUID
{
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    NSString *str = (__bridge NSString *)string;
    CFRelease(string);
    return str;
}
```

**Edited: Resolved by using vijay's following simple code**

```
NSUUID  *UUID = [NSUUID UUID];
NSString* stringUUID = [UUID UUIDString];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, you are getting this error because of `[DBManager GetUUID]` method, where you would release the `CFRelease(cfUuid)`.

To get the UUID, try this simplified API

```
+ (NSString *)GetUUID
{

    NSUUID  *UUID = [NSUUID UUID];
    NSString* stringUUID = [UUID UUIDString];

    return stringUUID;

}
```

Comment: then, still r u getting the message?

Comment: Thanks vijay, I replace my method code with your simplified API and then it's working well.

Answer (score 0):

After `CFUUIDCreateString`, you get a string you own. By using `__bridge`, you set `str` to the same string. So when you `CFRelease(string)` you do not own the memory backing `str` anymore...

To avoid this, either use a Cocoa method like @vijay says, or remove the `CFRelease` and use `__bridge_transfer NSString*` instead of `__bridge`. This tells the compiler you're transferring a CF object you own into the ARC world.

Per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html):

> __bridge_transfer or CFBridgingRelease moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers ownership to ARC. ARC is responsible
>   for relinquishing ownership of the object.

Comment: thanks Thomas Deniau for pointing out. I replaced my method with vijay's code and now it is working.